# Is there a way to add an event from the top panel calendar without opening up the calendar app?

Tags: calendar, top-bar

I just want a little "+" button on the top bar calendar so I can add events without having to go into the full calendar.

I think it would be very quick and useful for most people instead of a read-only solution in the top panel.

Does a solution exist for this? How do I go about implementing such a solution if it does not?

Comment: I was about to ask the same question mate. It is surprising not to have such a 'logical' feature...

Answer (score 0):

The idea indeed is nice. However, this is currently not implemented.

Implementing this yourself would require coding skills. It could likely be implemented by a Gnome Shell extension, that changes the calendar, or that replaces the current pop-up with an entirely new one.

You could file an enhancement issue. Issues for Gnome are maintained at https://gitlab.gnome.org/. Anyone can register and file issues, i.e. bugs, usability issues and enhancement request. However, chances that someone will quickly implement your idea are small, considering the large project and the in comparison limited number of developers working on it.